# LXTerminal does not display Urdu characters correctly

Tags: language, input-languages, gnome-terminal, language-pack, linux-terminal

I'm Chinese and I don't read Urdu, but I want to communicate better with Indians.

In `LXTerminal`, the output looks like this, with some characters rendered as wingdings:

[image: LXTerminal screenshot]

In `QTerminal` the output seems rendered correctly:

[image: QTerminal screenshot]

In `LXTerminal` if I run `localectl status` I get:

```
   System Locale: LANG=hi_IN.UTF-8
                  LC_TIME=C.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: us
      X11 Layout: us
       X11 Model: pc105
```

I also did `set LANG=hi_IN.UTF-8` and re-opened terminal, same result.

For reference, the text of the first 2 sentences above are here:

```
ہارت میں ہم رام مندر بنا رہے
اور وہاں پاکستان کو لوگ بم سے اڑا رہے
```

***DISCLAIMER**: The 2 sentences are saying something like: "We are building a Ram temple in our hearts, and there people are blowing up Pakistan with bombs." It's taken from a current YouTube video. I have no intention of spreading political biased views.*

English translation of the 2nd sentence should look like this:

[image: Urdu translation]

Comment: This looks like Arabic or some closely related script, most likely Urdu (due to the mention of Pakistan) to me. Hindi / Devanagari, used in India, is a totally different script. Of course you are absolutely free to configure Hindi locale and still expect Urdu to show up correctly. But the title of your question is wrong, you don't have a problem with Hindi characters, you have a problem with Arabic / Urdu or alike. You say you want to communicate with Indians in Hindi, you really need to first clear up this confusion in your head.

Comment: Have you tried a different font? Looks like a broken font to me.

Comment: Could you please also attach the source file? I did a websearch for the English snippet and it brings up recent news articles about some military conflict between two countries or nations. I'd appreciate if you could find a piece of text that's free of politics, and also replace the screenshots accordingly.

Comment: Also, what happens if you eliminate `more`, and instead use `cat` to print the file (or `head` to print the first 10 lines)? Does it change anything?

Comment: Source file is the beginning of a YouTube video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IisMEqc-LqU

Comment: @egmont:  I tried installing Arabic (there is no Urdu language pack in Ubuntu)... but still not displaying correctly.  I think the QTerminal displayed correctly.  Also, `more` vs `cat` does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: The YouTube auto-generated sub-title says the original language of the video is Hindi.  I machine speech-recognize the sound file into Hindi, but the displayed letters does not look like those in the YouTube sub-titles.  However, I put the speech-recognized text into Google Translate to English and it came out making sense.

Comment: How to download the subtitles from youtube? Also, it's still unclear to me: Do you have problems with Arabic or with Hindi text? New question: what does `echo $VTE_VERSION` say in LXTerminal?

Comment: VTE_VERSION of LXTerminal = 6003

Comment: (I added original text in the question as Unicode, you can try detect language)

Comment: It is a fact that can be verified from the news, so I hope it is not considered "politically biased".  Just like everyone knows that Ukraine and Russia are bombing each other these days.

Comment: @YanKingYin “…there is no Urdu language pack in Ubuntu…” That’s the problem. The text you are showing is Urdu. It is not Arabic. Maybe “Persian-Arabic?”

Comment: What about this [proposed solution on the Ask Ubuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/a/1291117/51813) site? “Install the `ibus-m17n` package and re-login. That will make the _Urdu (phonetic (m17n))_ input method available.” Or [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/557537/51813).

Comment: Bit of potential confusion here. I'm from the south and we speak a different language *but* both urdu and hindi I believe have similar phenetic roots. Your terminal screenshots are using an arabic style script (as Urdu does) and your google translate is in hindi with devanagari script. Looking at the youtuber's other videos - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4Y52u2hJbs is in hindi so the language of the videos ought to be hindi not urdu